# REACTjs | Getting this on Selection of option TypeError: state.users is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, web-development-server

**I am trying to post data using react to my database but when I select the option getting from axios I get an error state.users is indefined , I also receive a warning that**

***Warning:** A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen.*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import axios from "axios";
const CreateExercise = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    username: "",
    description: "",
    duration: 0,
    date: new Date(),
    users: [],
  });

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    setState({
      username: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const onChangeDescription = (e) => {
    setState({
      description: e.target.value,
    });};
  const onChangeDuration = (e) => {
    setState({
      duration: e.target.value,
    });};
  const onChangeDate = (date) => {
    setState({
      date: date,
    }); };

  console.log(reff.current)
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const exercise = {
      username: state.username,
      description: state.description,
      duration: state.duration,
      date: state.date,  };

    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/exercise/add", exercise).then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data); });};

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/users").then((doc) => {
      if (doc.data.length > 0) {
        setState({
          users: doc.data.map((user) => user.username),
          username: doc.data[1].username,
        }); } }); },[]);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-3">
          <h3 className="my-3 text-center">Create New Exercise Log</h3>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}> <div className="form-group">
              <label>Username: </label>
              <select required className="form-control" value={state.username}
                onChange={onChangeUsername} >
                {state.users.map(function (user) {
                  return ( <option key={user} value={user}>
                      {user}
                    </option>  );   })}  </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Description: </label>
              <input
                type="text"  required  className="form-control" value={state.description}
     onChange={onChangeDescription}
                  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Duration (in minutes): </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={state.duration}
                onChange={onChangeDuration} />

            </div> <div className="form-group">
              <div>
                <label className="mr-3">Date: </label>
                <DatePicker selected={state.date} onChange={onChangeDate} />
              </div>
            </div> <hr />
            <div className="form-group text-center">
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Create Exercise Log"
                className="btn btn-primary" /> </div> </form>  </div>
      </div></div> );};

export default CreateExercise;
```

Comment: place console.log at `if (doc.data.length > 0)`, do you get something?

Comment: Yea I get results in an array :
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing state at hooks are different from changing at previous class based component where `setState({ myKey: Myvalue })` would do the dirty work for you and only update `myKey` property. with hooks, that doesn't happen when your state is an object. that means that all other keys will be lost, hence `undefined`.

to avoid that you can pass a function to setState, where its param is currentState, and do as:

```
 setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  myKey: myValue,
}))
```